# React-native android fetch method crash app

Tags: android, curl, fetch, react-native, emoji

I tried curl my APIs :

> curl http://localhost:8080/0/me -H "Authorization: xxx"
>
> curl http://localhost:8080/0/me/contactlist -H "Authorization: xxx"

every thing work fine (both response in JSON Content-Length:1014 200OK 20ms)

But in Genymotion first API work correctly, second always crash with error( Unfortunately app has stopped) :(

edit : Add logcat (Sorry, I forget about adb logcat)

```
F/fbassert( 3233): Assert (/Users/mkonicek/code/react-native/ReactAndroid/src/main/jni/first-party/jni/LocalString.cpp:36): 4 byte utf-8 encodings only valid for up to 21 bits
F/libc    ( 3233): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xdeadb00c in tid 3262 (imit=5&offset=1)
I/DEBUG   (   87): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
I/DEBUG   (   87): Build fingerprint: 'generic/vbox86tp/vbox86tp:5.1/LMY47D/buildbot06101042:userdebug/test-keys'
I/DEBUG   (   87): Revision: '0'
I/DEBUG   (   87): ABI: 'x86'
I/DEBUG   (   87): pid: 3233, tid: 3262, name: imit=5&offset=1  >>> com.awesomeproject <<<
I/DEBUG   (   87): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0xdeadb00c
I/DEBUG   (   87): Abort message: 'Assert (/Users/mkonicek/code/react-native/ReactAndroid/src/main/jni/first-party/jni/LocalString.cpp:36): 4 byte utf-8 encodings only valid for up to 21 bits'
```

Comment: Just a guess here but maybe the down vote is because you didn't provide any meaningful info about your problem. "unknown error" is not good enough. You have to dig deeper and actually find the error causing your app to crash. First step would be to fire up logcat and check for errors and update the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I just know an issue.

In JSON response have emoji characters which may cause problem when js trying to decode it. But dont know why it cant catch by Promise, too bad.

Solution :

Server-side > parse to url escape string before encoding JSON

Client-side > parse value back using build-in decodeURI()